# Turning LED light on with Pi

Tags: power, camera, led

I am looking to build a home security camera with a LED light attachment. Many people mention they use a IR Illuminator for the light source which often seem to be DC 12V. I am not sure how one would turn this on and off with a raspberry pi.

Comment: Use a ULN2003A or similar.  Probably the cheapest solution unless you have your own transistors/diodes spare.

Answer (score 1):

Driving Relays directly from RPi GPIO might be a little dangerous. Additional circuit is required. Take a look at link below, it might answer all your questions in that topic.

http://www.openhomeautomation.net/control-a-relay-from-anywhere-using-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

For connecting high power devices (like an electric kettle - don't ask why) to RPi, i use relays. Be sure the voltage needed to turn the relay on is ~5V - the standard voltage of GPIO output.

Comment: GPIO is driven by 3.3volts? Possibly your relay works on a range from 2V-5V which you are lucky I suppose.

Comment: @ppumkin i used a doubleelay. the small one was 2~5vdc and using pi's 5v it turned on the big relay.